# Use Honeywell VisionPro without EIM?

Tags: wiring, thermostat

I just acquired a Honeywell VisionPro TH9421C1004 thermostat but I didn't get the Equipment Interface Module (EIM) with it.  Can I still wire this directly from my furnace?  It only has 3 wire connections: Data, R, and C.

Answer (score 0):

### No, you can't

Unfortunately, the Honeywell thermostats that use an EIM rely on it to translate either RedLink (for wireless versions) or a proprietary protocol (for the wired ones) to the 24VAC signals that a furnace understands.  So, since Honeywell discontinued the wired versions in favor of their RedLink counterparts, you'll need to hunt down a secondhand EIM for your thermostat.

Comment: since I only need it for a heat call, I can't just hook up the C & R?

Comment: @ChrisL -- you can't just hook up the C and R, the data line does complicated things instead of being a simple 24VAC on/off signal